# How to find files that don't contain a given search string

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expressions

I have a command that finds all the PDF files that contain the string "Font"

```
find /Users/me/PDFFiles/  -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec grep -H 'Font' '{}' ';'
```

How can I change this command such that it does the inverse? Finds all PDF files that do not contain the search string "Font"

Comment: `grep -v` seems to be fairly simple, have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks. No I did not try that. I found the grep "L" flag which does what I needed.

Comment: I don't think the "-v" option is going to do what you want, anyway, as it will output non-matching lines.

Comment: Yeah, mixed up exclude and invert, I did.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want to use the "-L" option of `grep`:

```
 -L, --files-without-match
         Only the names of files not containing selected lines are written to standard output.  Path-
         names are listed once per file searched.  If the standard input is searched, the string
         ``(standard input)'' is written.
```

Answer (score 9):

Just add the "L" flag. This does the inverse

```
find /Users/me/PDFFiles/  -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec grep -HL 'Font' '{}' ';'
```